# How can I address the UI Router 1.0 beta 3 error "No coreservices implementation for UI-Router is loaded. You should include one of: ['angular1.js']"

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

I updated to UI Router 1.0 beta 3. I've managed to update my Angular 1.5 app to use it, but Karma is giving me an error:

`No coreservices implementation for UI-Router is loaded. You should include one of: ['angular1.js'`

I've not been able to discover what's causing this or how to fix it.

Answer (score 0):

It seems to be caused by a test that was mocking $location.

Now to find another way to spy on $location inside a run block.